# How to add hidden attribute to a file in linux like windows does?

Tags: linux, windows, samba, kde-plasma

This is might a weird question.

ENVIRONMENT DESC:

SAMBA SERVER: LINUX, filesystem:XFS

CLIENT1: LINUX, DOLPHIN(KDE's file manager)

CLIENT2: WINDOWS 10

I open the folder through samba in windows client, and right click on the file 'a.txt' and set it 'Hidden'.

Then this file could not be seen in Linux Client's Dolphin File manager.

But of course this file could be seen in server's CLI via cmd:

```
ls
```

'ls -a' not needed.

i.e,  it's NOT a hidden file to linux.

But why dolphin could not show it(unless I press ctrl+h to show all hidden files)?

In another way to ask: what has windows done to the file to hide it?

When I need to hide some file in Linux, use a dot-led filename such as '.a.txt'.

So is there a way in Linux to add or read the 'Hidden' attribute of a file which was hidden by Windows, like 'attrib.exe' does?

Where is that 'Hidden' attribute data stored?

Comment: "Hidden" is just an attribute on a FAT or NTFS file.  Enumerators that don't check the attribute before showing it will treat it like an ordinary file.  If I'm not mistaken, `ls -a` just tells the command to not skip files that begin with `.`.  That's all `-a` does.

Comment: Linux filesystems don't work the same way as Windows ones. There is no hidden attribute.

Comment: 'There is no hidden attribute', but how does dolphin(a Linux program) know it's a hidden file(that file is hidden by windows)?